# Linear transformations defined by $T(v) = Av$. Find all of possible $v$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm stuck on a problem. The problem is this:

The linear transformation $T : \Bbb{R}^4 \to \Bbb{R}^2$ is defined by $T(v) = Av$, where

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 & -3 \end{bmatrix}$$

Find all vectors $v$ such that: $$T(v) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}$$

So I have forgotten how to do this. Do I:
- reduce $A$ to reduced row-echelon form (why do I do this? Is it because it's easy to solve once you have pivot columns and free variables)?
- rewrite the system of equations

Is this right:

\begin{align}
A &= \begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 & -3 \end{bmatrix} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 1 & -3 \\ 0 & -5 & -2 & 7 \end{bmatrix} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 1 & -3 \\ 0 & 1 & \frac{2}{5} & \frac{7}{5} \end{bmatrix} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{-29}{5} \\ 0 & 1 & \frac{2}{5} & \frac{7}{5} \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

so: $v_4 = t, v_3 = s, v_2 = \frac{-2}{5}s - \frac{7}{5}t, v_1 = \frac{-1}{5}s + \frac{29}{5}t$

$$\begin{bmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \\ v_3 \\ v_4 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{-1}{5}s + \frac{29}{5}t \\ \frac{-2}{5}s - \frac{7}{5} t \\ s + 0t \\ 0 + t \end{bmatrix} = s \begin{bmatrix} \frac{-1}{5} \\ \frac{-2}{5} \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + t \begin{bmatrix} \frac{29}{5} \\ \frac{-7}{5} \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} $$

Is this the set of all $v$?

**EDIT**

I messed up, the first $\frac{7}{5}$ should be a $\frac{-7}{5}$

Comment: It looks like you’ve made a mistake in your row reduction. If you multiply your last expression by $A$, you don’t get $0$.

Answer (score 1):

You found the solutions to the homogeneous system $Tv = 0$.

The solutions to the system $Tv = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}$ are of the form $$\left(\text{one particular solution to }Tv = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}\right) \quad + \quad\left(\text{ any solution of the homogeneous system }\right)$$

We can guess one solution as $v = \begin{bmatrix} \frac45 \\ \frac35 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$ so all solutions are of the form

$$v = \begin{bmatrix} \frac45 \\ \frac35 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} + s \begin{bmatrix} \frac{-1}{5} \\ \frac{-2}{5} \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + t \begin{bmatrix} \frac{29}{5} \\ \frac{-7}{5} \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

for some $s,t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* *Augment* the matrix $A$ with the column $\begin{pmatrix} 1\\2\end{pmatrix}$ and row-reduce the resulting augmented matrix.

So, row reduce $\left (\begin{array}{rrrr|r}2&-1&0&1&1\\1&2&1&-3 &2\end{array}\right ) $.

Answer (score 0):

Your way to solve systems of equations is absolutely correct. But you solved the wrong system. What you did is solving the system of equations $Ax=0$. But you need to solve $Ax=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: ohhhh stupidddddddd